# Rails Server Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting a routing error when trying to access the *web application* with the URL for the localhost.

*Ruby on Rails 3.2* and *Windows 7* is used.

## The Question:

Why does this routing error happen? And does anybody have a suggestion how to fix this?

## The URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/web_app_name
```

## The Error Message:

### In the Web Browser:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/web_app_name"
```

### In the Command Prompt:

```
Started GET "/web_app_name" for 127.0.0.1
    ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/web_app_name"):
      actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `ca ll'
      railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
      railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
      activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
      railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
      rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
      rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
      activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
      rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
      railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
      railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
      rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
      railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
      rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
      C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `servi        ce'
      C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
      C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in         start_thread'
      Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (78.0ms)
```

## Addendum:

### The "routes.rb" File:

web_app_name/config/routes.rb

```
WebAppName::Application.routes.draw do

end
```

### The rake routes Command:

The `rake routes` command does not produce an output in the *command prompt*.

Comment: Show us your `routes.rb` file, please. Do you have a route defined for `web_app_name`?

Comment: And output of `rake routes`.  But - I'm wondering what you see if you just visit `http://localhost:3000/` in your browser - the `web_app_name` part may be unnecessary to see your app.

Comment: I have edited the question and pasted the routes.rb, which is the one at default, after the `project template` creation.

Comment: I have run the command `rails generate controller home index` which did set the necessary route settings for it to work. The `command prompt` and Sublime Text 2 are a good combination.

Comment: You should really accept jan267's answer as correct because it was absolutely correct (you were missing a route in the routes.rb draw block.) Otherwise, add and accept a specific answer (posting the contents of your routes.rb) so other's can benefit from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the route in `routes.rb` file ?! Show it, please!

It should be something like:

```
root :to => "controller_name#action_name"
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct -- no route is spec'd in routes.rb.